# Получить элемент по содержимому блока

Tags: python, selenium

Есть такой див блок `<div class="test" id="o1"> Тестовый блок </div>`
как при помощи selenium из содержимого блока -  `Тестовый блок` получить содержимое  `class`, `id` и кликнуть по элементу?

Comment: Вам нужно получить элемент по его контенту?

Comment: да, я так понимаю проблема может возникнуть в том, что одинакового контента может оказаться несколько

Comment: и так же получить егоclass и id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Текстовый блок')]")`
И уже у найденных элементов вытаскивайте айти и класс.